# Openpyxl column number formatting

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

Im using openpyxl to append formated dataframe rows to existing excel file/creating new with following code:

```
    if os.path.isfile(transformed_file): #if file exists, load and append
        workbook = openpyxl.load_workbook(transformed_file)
        sheet = workbook['Sheet1']  
        for row in dataframe_to_rows(df, header=False, index=False):
            sheet.append(row)
            workbook.save(transformed_file) 
            workbook.close()
    else:  # create the excel file if doesn't already exist
        with pd.ExcelWriter(path = transformed_file, engine = 'openpyxl') as writer:
            df.to_excel(writer, index=False, sheet_name = 'Sheet1')
```

I need to format column 'G' as a plain number '0', at the moment when opening excel file the format is '1.23E+10'.

How could this be achieved for the sample above? Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Hello try the following code see if it works for you:

```
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
ws['A1'] = 123455656565464563302589013
ws['B1'] = 123455656565464563302589013
ws['A1'].number_format = '0'  # Number formatting
ws['B1'].number_format = '0.00E+00'  # Scientific formatting
wb.save("formating_test.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution which worked for me. Realized from documentation that one has to iterate through each cell.

```
for cell in sheet[('D')]:
    cell.number_format ='0'
```